# make the scope values same after location.path()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-routing

On click of a button I want to change the template with the same model value. I am using location.path to change the template.

Plunk- http://plnkr.co/edit/FVkSj2vs8WDAt1eifBpF?p=preview

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('includeExample', ['ngRoute']);

   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the about page
            .when('/template2', {
                templateUrl : 'template2.html',
                controller  : 'ExampleController'
            })


    });

app.controller('mainController', [function($scope) {


}]);

  app.controller('ExampleController', [function($location, $scope) {

    $scope.locationChange = function(){
      $location.path('/template2');

    }

  }]);
```

template1.html

```
Content of template1.html
<br/>
<input ng-model="x"/>
<button ng-click='locationChange()'> Submit</button>
{{x}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) directive. You could use it like this:

```
<div ng-switch="location">
  <div ng-switch-when="template1">
    <div ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="template2">
    <div ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then maintain scope.location (set it to either template1 or template2) when clicking your button.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service that caches the $scope.

```
.factory('appData', [function() {
  var cache = {};
  return {
    set: function(location, payload) {
      cache[location] = payload;
    },
    get: function(location) {
      return cache[location];
    },
    clear: function() {
      cache = {};
    }
  };
});
```

Then in your controller/directive, simply include appData as a dependency and call

```
appData.set('cacheScope', $scope);
```

And to retrieve it:

```
$scope = appData.get('cacheScope');
```

Comment: have tried creating service but view is not getting updated with the values

Comment: Can you show create a fiddle or plunkr to show how you are using this? Without seeing your code, it's difficult to give any more direction.